# Algorithm for pathing between graph components

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

First, this is a homework question. I have a boolean matrix where 1s represent nodes, and adjacent nodes are considered connected.
for example:

1 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 0 0
1 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0

This matrix contains 3 groups by the definition I've been given. One in the top left, consisting of 5 nodes, one in the top right consisting of 1 node, and one below that consisting of 2 nodes.
  What I need to do is write a function(s) that determines the fewest number of nodes that must be added to the matrix in order to connect all of the separate components. Two groups are connected when a path can be made from any node in one group to the other.

So, what I'm asking is for someone to shove me in the right direction in terms of algorithms. I've considered how I might use path finding algorithms to find the shortest path between two groups, but am unsure of how I could do this for every group in the matrix. If I use a depth first traversal to determine the separate groups, could I then use a path finding algorithm for any arbitrary node within each group to another?

Comment: Seems a tough problem! One approach can be to first identify such islands, compute pair-wise shortest distance between those islands and get an upper bound on the number of 0 to 1 conversions. Then recursively try to reduce this number and see if its possible. As I said, this approach is highly inefficient and I think there should be a better way.

Comment: A disjoint-set is also good for finding the separate groups.  Breadth-first search is good at determining shortest paths, because you "radiate out" slowly.  I agree with @AbhishekBansal this is a tough problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider every connected component(group) as a node. Then you can run MST (Minimum Spanning Tree) algorithm to find the min cost to connect all the groups.

Complexity: Complexity to build the edges = O(M*M) + O(ElgV) (M is the number of 1's on the the given grid and M*M operations to find Manhattan distance every pair of 1's to find the Manhattan distance of every pair of groups) and O(ElgV) is the complexity of finding MST

Comment: What are the nodes and edges in the graph you're computing an MST of? Wouldn't an MST also connect up the intermediary nodes even if they aren't used?

Comment: @templatetypedef: first: **Consider every connected component(group) as a node.** second:M is the number of 1's on the the given grid and M*M operations to find Manhattan distance every pair of 1's **to find the Manhattan distance of every pair of groups**
While thinking about the intermediary nodes in your question, I understood, MST won't work here :) Will update the ans. Thanks

Comment: After looking through some of the things you guys have mentioned, I think this is the best way to go about it. Since I only need to output the number of nodes necessary to connect all the components, the Manhattan distance can be calculated between each component's nearest nodes, and then take the shortest distance from one component through every other component.
Thanks for the input, folks.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but how does the MST info tell you what squares to light up? There might be many different routes of the same length that connect all the clusters, but some might be better than others because you could share 1s between them. Moreover, why must the optimal structure be an MST? Maybe the best option introduces some intermediary join points. Think about three clusters in a T shape. It might be better to join them in a T than to join two independent pairs.

Answer (score 3):

The generic problem is called [the Steiner Tree problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree), and it is NP-complete.

There is an algorithm that's not exponential, but gives you a suboptimal solution.

The way you can do it is to compute shortest paths between any two pair of components, do the minimum spanning tree on using just the initial components and the weights you computed, then go through you solution and eliminate cycles.

Since you have a bunch of options for connecting islands I would add a step to optimize the connections.

But an algorithm for the optimal answer: NP-complete (try every combination).

Comment: You can solve this problem with a Steiner tree solver, but that doesn't mean that it's necessarily NP-hard. To show NP-hardness, you'd have to prove that you can reduce the Steiner tree problem to this problem, not the other way around.

Comment: I said at the start that the generic problem is NP hard. I also don't have any idea of how to use the extra constraints to optimize the solution. From the theoretical perspective you're right. From the practical perspective you can implement the NP solution and get it working.

Comment: Isn't this rectilinear Steiner tree problem, which is also NP-hard?